# how to loop img tag using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have images in my DB,  need to Loop that images using AJAX,

try this code but its not working,

```
<div id="NIC"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function($){
            NewUserConfirmData();

            function NewUserConfirmData(query = '') {
            //alert(query);   
            $("#Mangala").empty();
                $.ajax({
                url: 'live_search_NewUserConfirmData',
                method: 'GET',
                datatype:'json',
                data:{SearchKey:query},
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                //alert("done"); 
                $.each(data, function(index, val) {
                $('#NIC').append("<img src='{{ asset('storage/'"+val.NIC+")}} alt="" />")

                });
                })
                .fail(function() {
                    //alert("fail")
                    console.log("error");
                })
            }

            //$("#search_BTN").click(function(){
            $(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){    
                var query = $("#search").val();
                NewUserConfirmData(query);
            });

        });
</script>
```

val.NIC = SjFXIYmrvcHxjsgysfHNKcxqCViJQVz1wL78BOkI.png

so  try this code

```
<img src='{{ asset('storage/SjFXIYmrvcHxjsgysfHNKcxqCViJQVz1wL78BOkI.png')}}" alt="" title="" />
```

this is working,

need help to solve this

Comment: why you used {{ asset ?

Answer (score 0):

You use some backend function helper in a wrong way.

Your **{{ asset('storage/name.png')}}** will excute only in the server which only renders some string url pointing to your assets folder.

You can either not to use **assset()** by specifying the path to your assets

So in your `$.each()` code, assuming that your assets url is **/assets/storage/**

`$('#NIC').append("<img src='/assets/storage/" + val.NIC + "' alt='' />")`

Or you just edit the response of the backend to return absolute path so you can do this

`$('#NIC').append("<img src='" + val.NIC + "' alt='' />")`

Comment: You must aware what does your assets(resource) returns, since your'e using laravel, it basically add the host url with the string yo provided. Inspecting the element on browser can help